# How to know what to study based on past examinations?

Tags: self-learning

### TL;DR:

---

Tell me which topics should i study the most, based on this three tests:

Mathematics (A):
[2020](https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/ja/_mt/2021/06/2020_ga_math_a.pdf)
[2019](https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/ja/_mt/2021/06/2019_ga_math_a.pdf)
[2018](https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/ja/_mt/2021/06/2018_ga_math_a.pdf)

This question may sound a bit weird, since the natural answer would be "study whats already is on the test" but i'm wanna share a bit of context for this.

##### Context:

---

So i'm currently studying for the Japanese Scholarship known as MEXT in which every year the japanese embassy of each country gave the opportunity to enroll on a japanese university and go to study in that country. As an undergraduate student this is a big deal specially if there's a lack of opportunities in your current country.

I also want you to know that here in my country, there is a lack of proper mathematical education when it comes to high school, pretty much anyone who obtained a bachelor degree's are not well prepared to face one of this japanese test designed for undergraduate students since the test, present to you calculus, trigonometry, modular-arithmetic, number-theory, etc. problems which you don't see until you reach third semester of any university engineer-based career (at least here where i live)

Finally i want to tell that i've been studying calculus for a bit and i do know the basics and i don't have any problem with arithmetic or algebra.

### So here is the question:

---

Could somebody look at those test and tell me which topics should i study the most? Below you will find the three test that were used in past examinations and contains all the questions, i also will leave a link to the answers in case someone want to deep onto this:

[2020](https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/ja/_mt/2021/06/2020_ga_math_a.pdf) → [Answers](https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/ja/_mt/2021/06/2020_ga_math_a_ans.pdf)
[2019](https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/ja/_mt/2021/06/2019_ga_math_a.pdf) → [Answers](https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/ja/_mt/2021/06/2019_ga_math_a_ans.pdf)
[2018](https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/ja/_mt/2021/06/2018_ga_math_a.pdf) → [Answers](https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/ja/_mt/2021/06/2018_ga_math_a_ans.pdf)

##### Current approach and status:

---

In my current approach i tried solving most of the exercises presented and always fall in the same loop of no knowing, research, try solving, fail, research again, try solving again, failing, and finally making a question here. This of course may not be the best for a huge variety of topic since you have to make sure to **understand** what you are doing before going into any kind of examination but with so many themes its hard to pick one thing to study since you're pretty much dropping everything else in order to solve only one thing.

[image: flow chart]

#### The ideal:

---

When making this post i'm hoping someone could orient me through a path of things i should know and preferably master in order to be well prepared for the test.

Comment: I feel bad for saying this because you’ve clearly put a lot of thought and effort into this post, which we really appreciate, but it doesn’t make too much sense to have this question answered here. We generally stay away from personal advice questions since we don’t know you, your school and how you learn, on a close level. Any advice you receive here must be taken with a pinch of salt, since it would be conjectural and not authoritative.

Comment: i think any advice it's better than keep improvising my studies, just answer honestly from your point of view.

Comment: I am very much amazed and impressed by your attempt to formalize the process of studying itself. I can't really reward because I am not in charge of the people who hold exams and all, but if I could, I really would.

Comment: I think this stackexchange site would be better for this: (https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I found video training for mext on youtube. You could explore the specific training material available online.

Comment: I think of one thing when I see this. When we study for an exam, we often lose sight of how everything fits in together like the connections between topics. Usually highschool tests depend on how many specific things you can do rather than how well you understand the general flow and connectivity.

Comment: @Aplateofmomos that seems nice, but i nead at least 10 points to post more than 8 links.

Comment: Idea:You could comment the remaining links if there are more

Comment: @Gribouillis i've already seem most of those videos you mention, the thing with it is that most videos jump right into the solution without caring to much for explanation about what is going on or which criteria is being used when answering the question

Comment: I'm usually quite bad at explaining, but if it's worth anything I offer occasional problem help in this [SE chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120404/buraians-not-so-secret-hideout). So if you have specific stuff you want to discuss or need help with you can send a message, and I'll check it out when I procrastinate

Comment: I've found 500 pages ebook guide claiming to give step by step solutions. Explore search engines!

Comment: @Gribouillis could you provide a link to the mentioned ebook? It's not like i don't know the answer, i just don't know the metodology to get the result

Comment: https://myjapaneseexperience.com/product/math-undergrad-mext-scholarship/ but I don't know if it is good.

Comment: Instead of asking stackexchange for help when you cannot solve a problem, maybe find tests/exercises with (step by step) solutions to save time.

Comment: @TymaGaidash maybe i wasn't clear enough (since the diagram it's only for illustrative purposes) When facing a new problem that i cannot understand or cannot resolve i try by search everywhere (google, youtube, here, books, asking real life people) This q&a forum is by no means my first option, but it's one of the most reliable.